# Pass props through Route with HOC

Tags: reactjs

I have this Router, any page that should has the Layout is wrapped with the `withLayout` HOC.

I need to pass to some of the pages the user context, how can I add a `user` prop?

```
const withLayout = () => Component => props => (
  <div css={pageWrap}>
    <Header user={props.user} />
    <Component {...props} />
  </div>
);

export default function Router() {
  return (
    <AuthConsumer>
      {({ user }) => (
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={withLayout()(Home, { user })} />
          <Route exact path="/page1" component={withLayout()(Page1)} />
          <Route exact path="/page2" component={withLayout()(Page2)} />
        </Switch>
      )}
    </AuthConsumer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work like this:

```
<Route exact path="/" render={props => withLayout()(Home)({ ...props, user })} />
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you have problem with your `withLayout`. It should be:

```
const withLayout = () => (Component, props = {}) => (
  <div css={pageWrap}>
    <Header user={props.user} />
    <Component {...props} />
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

What's AuthConsumer?

You could use `contextType  = AuthContext` inside your page components. [[from](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#classcontexttype)]

```
class MyClass extends React.Component {
  static contextType = MyContext;
  render() {
    let value = this.context;
    /* render something based on the value */
  }
}
```

Comment: `AuthConsumer` is a context for the user's info